# How do I get a regular expression that starts with this phrase?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression that takes phrases inside a larger string that start with "st". It has to be case insensitive and searches through the whole strings and gives me back the number of matches.

What I have:

```
/st+/ig
```

I am testing it on:

```
st stuff pistuff stuff
stuff st st st st stuff notstuff
STUFF STUFF STUFF
sti
stiiiiii
stiiii
stufff
stiufff
```

It matches almost everything correctly, except it is also picks up pistuff and notstuff.

Comment: Start the regex with `^` to *anchor* it at the beginning of the test string.

Comment: I tried that and it only gives me one result. I want it on the beginning of the words, not the string.

Comment: use `\b` as I have stated in my answer.

Comment: The `+` is probably not doing what you think it's doing. The `+` quantifier matches one or more of the immediately preceding item. In this case, it's the 't'. So `/\bst+/` will only match 'st' in 'stuff' but will match 'sttt' in 'stttuf'. If you wish to match the entirety of any word beginning with 'st', use `/\bst[^\b]*\b/` which matches "a word boundary, followed by the string 'st' followed by zero or more non-word-boundary characters until a word boundary is found"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated** to capture words that start with `st` or just the two characters `st`, case-insensitive:

- For whole word matches: `/\bst\w*/ig`
- For matches, without needing to match entire word: `/\bst/ig`

`\b` is used to mark a word boundary.

```js
var strArr = [
  'st stuff pistuff stuff',
  'stuff st st st st stuff notstuff',
  'STUFF STUFF STUFF',
  'sti',
  'stiiiiii',
  'stiiii',
  'stufff',
  'stiufff'
];

var re = /\bst\w*/ig;
var count = 0;

strArr.forEach(function(str) {
  count += str.match(re).length;
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str.match(re) + '<br>');
});

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'count: ' + count);
```

Also, [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oH0rM9/3)

Comment: I think you probably want `/(?:\bst)+/` - your `+` matches one or more `t` characters :)

Comment: Ah yes...:) I will edit that.

Comment: There is no point in using a non-capturing group if it groups a single obligatory branch. It only hampers regex execution. The `+` in the OP regex was a typo.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It should have been obvious to me. Not sure how I missed it.

Comment: The "/\bpi+/ig" expression is working when I test it. Why did you take out the + and add "\w*"?

Comment: `\bpi+/ig` matches words of the following pattern: `pi`, `pii`, `piii`, etc. It will match just the `pi` in `pie`. Did you want to match the entire word as long as it starts with your predefined criteria? If so, the \w* makes the regex match the entire word that starts with your predefined criteria.

Comment: Oh, I see, I think I know why I am getting it correct. Your updated regex matches the whole word, while the older one matches those two first characters on phrases that start with it. Regardless, either expression are giving me the results I want, because all I need is the word count of those phrases and not the whole word returned.

Comment: I'll fix it right now.